# Injuries to stuntmen during filming

Tags: stunts

If an injury occurs to a stuntman during filming (in Hollywood), who typically covers the bill? Do stuntmen (stuntpersons) perhaps have special contracts or insurance policies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description of sample stunt performer contracts on [this web page](http://www.independentfilmmakercontracts.com/products-page/stunt-performer-insurance-carried-by-stunt-performer/) describes two versions: one in which the performer is required to purchase all necessary insurance, and one in which the producer pays for the insurance.  So the answer seems to be that there is no fixed way of handling this; it may go one way or the other.

[Another web page](http://www.ehow.com/list_7308954_types-insurance-stunt-artists.html) mentions the same two possibilities, but suggests that it is more common for the performers to carry their own insurance, often obtained through the Screen Actors Guild.